# Undefined offset: 2 when I delete an element of the array and I want to return the rest of them

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting this error whenever I try to delete and element in the array. It only work when I delete everything. But I want to delete one by one.
this is delete function

```
 public function delete($id){

      $user_id = auth() ->user()->id;
      $card = travel_plan::all()->where('travel_id', $user_id);
      foreach($card as $cardId){
        $cardd = $cardId;
    }  //->where('city_name', $uo)->first();
      $cardd->delete();

  return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'Post Removed');
```

}

this is my delete button

```
 {!!Form::open(['action'=>['TravelPlanController@delete','id' =>$cardd[]],'method'=>'POST','class'=>''])!!}
```

this is how I retrieved the id

```
 $cardd = array();
      $card = travel_plan::all()->where('travel_id', $user_id);
     foreach($card as $cardId){
          $cardd [] = $cardId ->id;
      }
```

Comment: how can I delete only one card

Comment: I have posted my answer.

Comment: you want to delete only one card ?

Comment: are you sure this return a value in your form, $cardd[1]] ?

Comment: I want to delete card by card I put one because I wanted to test and see if it will delete the card[1].

Comment: show your route for delete please

Comment: you are deleting travel plan but you are passing user_id of it, make your codes more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `travel_plan` which has `$id`, and just get all the rest

```php
travel_plan::where('travel_id', $id)->delete();
$cardd = travel_plan::where('travel_id', $user_id)->pluck('id')->first();
```

```html
@if (!empty($cardd))
{!!Form::open(['action'=>['TravelPlanController@delete','id' =>$cardd],'method'=>'POST','class'=>''])!!}
@endif
```

Comment: I tried but it is not deleting now. It is returning home with all the card.

Comment: @MamadouBellaDiallo u just want to show one of the rest?  I just use `$cardd[0]` to display one of it. did u have other codes loop `$cardd`?

Comment: actually what I want is to put an array of Ids so whenever you click delete for specific card it will delete that one only base on the id.

Comment: @MamadouBellaDiallo For laravel4, you can use lists() to get all the `id`, the codes will be cleaner. I have updated it

Comment: I am using laravel 5

Comment: @MamadouBellaDiallo you need to change the tag, your tag is `laravel-4`.and `laravel-5.1` have `lists`method, what specific version you used. And you can use `pluck('id')->toarray()` to get all the `id` instead of loop.

Comment: ok I did not released it. In delete button how can I place cardd[] without having to put the array number.

Comment: @MamadouBellaDiallo `->first()` to get the first value. and just render it

Comment: I still do not know what is wrong it is returning with all cards without deleting any.

Comment: @MamadouBellaDiallo your code just put the travel_plan to `$cardd ` in loop, so `$cardd ` is an object, and the object is deleted at last. so `$cardd` is empty. and you even don't use the `$id` from post.

Comment: @MamadouBellaDiallo it doesn't matter. if it helps, plz accept the answer.

Comment: @MamadouBellaDiallo Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206682/discussion-between-tsaikoga-and-mamadou-bella-diallo).

Comment: @MamadouBellaDiallo if you click the link, `$id` will pass to backend. and `travel_plan::where('travel_id', $id)->delete();` will delete that `id`,and return the rest `travel_plan`'s `id`

Comment: the $cardd actually is only returning one Id; not an array of Ids. I just checked;

Comment: @MamadouBellaDiallo yes, because I use `->first()`, if you want the array you can use `travel_plan::where('travel_id', $user_id)->pluck('id')`

Comment: thanks it got fixed. I changed travel_id to id; Now it is working